# Testing if a class is called in Python

Tags: python

I am a novice Python developer - but many years working with VB.  I have a Python app that I am using to get trade prices from Interactive Brokers. When the trade prices come in, I write them to a log file. I thought it was working fine, but now it does not seem to work.   Here is the Class that I use.  Is there something I can do to test whether this class is getting called?

```
class BerryWrapper(EWrapper):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):
        with open('log_me.txt','a') as file:
            if (field == 4):
                print 'Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
                file.write('Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))
            elif (field == 1):
                print 'Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
                file.write('Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))
            elif (field == 2):
                print 'Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
                file.write('Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))
```

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental about this question, because it seems like just a `print '\a'` under the method definition should settle the question of whether the method is being called.

Comment: @CalculatingNut Dropping `1/0` in the same place works even if your laptop is muted.

Comment: Thanks!  I will add this right away.

Comment: Do you mean the class or the method inside your class?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, a quick print statement will tell you if your class / method is being called.  But for longer-term instrumentation as your Python projects grow, I highly recommend [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.htmls).  Python's logging is very flexible and configurable and will serve you well for both run-time errors and debugging.  Your problem could be that your class isn't being called, your method isn't being called, or that you have an unexpected field value.  Logging can tell you which of these is the problem.  You should leave the logging in the code for future problem solving.  Here is your code with logging

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='logging.log',
    format='%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('BerryWrapper')

#class BerryWrapper(EWrapper):
class BerryWrapper(object):  # don't have EWrapper class for logging example

    log.debug('defined')
    def __init__(self):
        log.debug('called')
        pass          

    def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):
        log.debug('called')
        with open('log_me.txt','a') as file:
            log.debug('field %s', field)
            if (field == 4):
                log.info('Last[%s,%s,%s]', tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
                file.write('Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecu
            elif (field == 1):
                log.info('Bid[%s,%s,%s]', tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
                file.write('Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecut
            elif (field == 2):
                log.info('Ask[%s,%s,%s]', tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)
                file.write('Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecut
            else:     
                log.error('unexpected field value %s', field)


berry_wrapper = BerryWrapper()
berry_wrapper.tickPrice('id1', 1, '1.15', 'yes')
berry_wrapper.tickPrice('id1', 2, '2.25', 'yes')
berry_wrapper.tickPrice('id1', 3, '3.25', 'yes')
berry_wrapper.tickPrice('id1', 4, '4.25', 'yes')
```

Here's the output in logging.log:

```
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:BerryWrapper:11 defined
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:__init__:13 called
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:17 called
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:19 field 1
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:24 Bid[id1,1.15,yes]
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:17 called
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:19 field 2
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:27 Ask[id1,2.25,yes]
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:17 called
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:19 field 3
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:30 unexpected field value 3
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:17 called
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:19 field 4
    2015-01-23 11:50:43,007 BerryWrapper:tickPrice:21 Last[id1,4.25,yes]
```